# bigcommerce stencil display a brand's image

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to display an image but it is not working as expected

```
{{#each shop_by_brand}}
    {{image}} // returns nothing
    <img src="{{getImage image "thumbnail"}}"> // src is '[object,object]'
{{/each}}
```

Comment: The shop_by_brand object doesn't have an image property: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/brand-resources#ShopByBrand Which template are you trying to show brand images in?

Comment: im using an altered version of cornerstone

Comment: Which template file? Meaning, where on the storefront are you trying to display brand images?

Comment: I am in a custom template. so none that you would recognize. It is a child of header. Cornerstone ships with the brands in the footer. If we could show images there that would solve my problem too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surfacing brand images on the homepage would require making a storefront API request.

One way to do this would be to use Stencil utils to make a request to /brands/:
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/stencil-utils-api-reference#API-js

By default, the request returns HTML, but the function can take a presentation template as an argument; this could be a custom template that filters the page through a {{json brands}} helper.

Another way to access the full brands object in the header would be to use the v3 catalog API. You could use AWS Lambda/Amazon API Gateway as a lightweight solution for hosting a function that calls the API and returns brands.image_url data.

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/catalog.html?json#getbrands